# Booting ubuntu from grub after reinstall

Tags: ubuntu, boot, grub, bootloader, grub2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I can't boot to Ubuntu after installing Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/254737/i-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-after-installing-windows-7)

Hello all,  I recently added another partition to my hardrive where ubuntu was installed to and afterwards when I booted ubuntu I got sent to the grub rescue> terminal.  The fix for that was that I had to reinstall grub on the correct partition for ubuntu to boot again.  So I followed all the instructions from ubuntu to fix it from the live cd here https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling%20GRUB%202 .

After I was done doing that I rebooted and the grub> terminal is now there. I would usually see a list to choose from with my os but Im guessing I have to update grub when I reboot or load the menu list.  The problem is I did a lot of research to figure out how to boot from grub> but I cannot find a way to do so.

It is not easy finding a tutorial for doing so and I am completley stuck.  I would like to know an easy way to boot into my ubuntu from grub and making the booting as it was before I made the partition.  Please any help would be greatly appreciated for I need to get on my ubuntu to start doing some work...

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/254737/i-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-after-installing-windows-7

Comment: dude this wasnt a duplicate I did that already this is what to do after the grub was reinstalled .  Read the post before you go closing my posts.  That other one is just to reinstall the grub.

Comment: http://forums.scotsnewsletter.com/index.php?act=ST&f=14&t=5025 - first result in google for 'grub prompt'