# PC won't identify Linux Live USB. "non-system disk or disk error replace and strike any key when ready"

Tags: windows-7, linux, boot, usb, bootable-media

I installed Mint 19.1 Cinnamon and it was working poorly. The USB port were not identifying flash drives. I tried lots and lots of things (really, lots of possibilities), but nothing worked. Then I installed Windows 7 to another partition, and then I did not get any boot menu and automatically Windows boot.

So i tried a lot more things (https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/fix-ubuntu-linux-pc-wont-boot/ and [I can't boot to Ubuntu after installing Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/254737/i-cant-boot-to-ubuntu-after-installing-windows-7)). The same linux live usb, another linux (Mint 19 XFCE), even live usb Windows 7 did not worked. I tried to Repair Windows boot (https://appuals.com/fix-non-system-disk-or-disk-error-message-on-startup/). Nothing... Only:

```
non-system disk or disk error replace and strike any key when ready [...]
```

I got desperate and deleted all linux partitions (root, swap and home) with windows disk manager. Tried the live USBs again and only windows is working (LINUXs are not).

I also tried EasyBCD to make a initialisation for the live USB linux. No success.

I don't what else I can do. I am hopeless. I would like to know: I a formatted everything with Windows 7 will I be able to install linux again?

Please help me.

Comment: Are you sure the USB (ports/controller/hub/cables/drive) isn't broken?

Comment: That error message would imply to me that the software has not been installed on the disk correctly. Is the problem with the hard drive, and if so, is thr BIOS set to legact boot? (Its probably a GRUB error)

Comment: Only flshdrives were not working. All other USB devices were fine. But on Windows every USB devices (including drives) were fine.

Comment: How do I change these BIOS settings?